# "$(...).accordion is not a function" error in multipage mobile app

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried in vain to search for a solution to the problem. I am a newbie to jQuery and I basically don't understand the part about inclusion of jQuery header files.The app seems to run fine if it is just in the index page but once I make it a multipage app,this error comes up. Here is my index.html code:

```
    <html>
       <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>index</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--application UI goes here-->
        <div id="AuthBody">
            <div id="loginForm">

                    <input type="text" name="username" id="usernameInputField" placeholder=username data-clear-btn="true"><br/> <br/><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordInputField" placeholder=password data-clear-btn="true"><br/>
                    <br/>
                <input type="button" id="loginButton" value="Sign In" onclick="signIn();"/>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="ResTable"></div>
```

This is my second page html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <div id="FlowDetailsPage">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div id="accordion">

                 <h3>A flow</h3>
                 <div>
                    <progress id="progressBar_A" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                     <span id="status_A"></span><br>
                    <div id="finalMessage_A"></div>
                    <div id="A"></div><br><br>
                </div>

                <h3>B flow</h3>
                <div>
                    <progress id="progressBar_B" value="0" max="100"></progress>
                    <span id="status_B"></span><br>
                    <div id="finalMessage_B"></div>
                    <div id="B"></div><br><br>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>`
```

And this is the function for multi page load:

```
function getLoginSuccess(result){
    var pwd=document.getElementById('passwordInputField').value;
    var singIn_resSet = result.invocationResult.resultSet[0];//PWD

    if(pwd.trim()==singIn_resSet.PASSWORD.trim()) {
        alert("Login Successful");
        $("#ResTable").load("pages/FlowDetailsPage.html", function(){
            $("#AuthBody").hide();
        });
    } else 
        loginFailed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the head and the body tag form the second page 
put jquery ui in the first page and call it like this:

mainpage:

```
    <html>
           <head> 
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>index</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            <div id="AuthBody">
                <div id="loginForm">

                        <input type="text" name="username" id="usernameInputField" placeholder=username data-clear-btn="true"><br/> <br/><br>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="passwordInputField" placeholder=password data-clear-btn="true"><br/>
                        <br/>
                    <input type="button" id="loginButton" value="Sign In" onclick="signIn();"/>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div data-role="page" id="ResTable"></div>
```

second page:

```
<div id="FlowDetailsPage">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div id="accordion">

                <h3>A flow</h3>
                <div>A flow has completed
                    </div>

                <h3>B flow</h3>
                <div>
                    B flow is running</div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

js:

```
 function getLoginSuccess(result){
        var pwd=document.getElementById('passwordInputField').value;
        var singIn_resSet = result.invocationResult.resultSet[0];//PWD

        if(pwd.trim()==singIn_resSet.PASSWORD.trim()) {
            alert("Login Successful");
            $("#ResTable").load("pages/FlowDetailsPage.html", function(){
                $("#AuthBody").hide();
                $("#accordion").accordion();
            });
        } else 
            loginFailed();
    }
```

Comment: I tried out your solution..the page gets loaded but then it still is giving the error and has stopped displaying as an accordion itself..actually after the second page gets loaded I have to call another function as well..I thought that was not important but left it out..any idea is that could be the reason for it?

Comment: getLoginSuccess has to be called after the the dom is loaded

Comment: yeah I have called the getLoginSuccess in a seperate js file.It authenticates the username and password via adapter and returns the result.When the passwords match,I have to call another function that loads content into the accordion. basically the flow progress is calculated.if I place it before the accordion load,it shows as normal progress bars without the accordion functionality.And if I place it after that,the accordion does get loaded but not with the flow progress value

Comment: you mean that the content of the accordion is created dinamicly by js and than loaded in this page?

Comment: its not exactly dynamic..there is a progress bar and certain other elements that are static as shown in the edited code of my question..the values of these are filled in dynamically via js